# Porch swing Supports

Tags: joists, hanging

Trying to hang a porch swing but the overhead structure isnt conducive. Joists are all 2x6 that run perpendicular to the direction I need to hang the swing. I’m thinking of putting a couple 4x4s in between the joists and drilling into the 4x4s from below.  But Im concerned about ability of the 2x6s to bear the weight. Any thoughts on using face mounting joist hangers to hang a 4x4 (and in-turn the swing)?  And the best way to do it.  House is 98 yrs old so I dont want to screw anything up. Attached picture shows the overheas structure of the porch.  The red circles are the two points where I need to drill in from below.  Thanks for any assistance. [image]

Comment: Joist hangers don't do anything to alleviate the strain on the ceiling joists.

Comment: You'd need more support than what those three joists provide. I think if I was doing it I'd either want to truss the joists up to the rafters in a V configuration for stability, or I'd build a simple frame to support the swing from below on posts. It could be anchored to the ceiling for longitudinal stability.

Comment: Understand that. Sorry if question wasn't clear.  Can the 2x6 existing joists support a 4x4 hung with face mounted joist hangers in between.  The issue is that there are no existing joists where I need to hang the swing.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Getting a little outside of my DIY comfort zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a structural analysis that considers the load on the roof, ceiling load, and the proposed swing load. Way too many variables to address here. If you can’t handle the structural analysis, you can do it the old fashioned way. Put a piece of plywood across the ceiling members and add 50 lbs and measure the deflection. Keep adding weight to 1.5 times the weight you plan on the swing. Don’t exceed 3/8” deflection at the center of the room.

My gut tells me that your roof won’t support the load without truss support to spread the load.

Comment: Ok; thanks.  The porch has the same as the rest of the house.  The rest of the attic has trusses up to the rafters about every 3 ft, but the area over the porch does not for some reason.

Comment: *Porch has same roof as the rest of the house.